# JavaScript to change div before rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a webpage with a few divs on it, the first thing to happen is detect if scripts are enabled, if they are not the page can render as it is now, but if javascript is enabled i need to change the size of the divs

Is there anyway to hide a div before it's shown on screen so I can resize it with javascript then make it visible again?

So the goal:

1. User clicks on page link
2. If scripts are not enabled, do nothing
3. If scripts are enabled, hide the div.
4. Resize the div
5. Show the div and show it on screen

How can i organize my 3 script calls to achieve this?

1. Function-1: hideDiv()
2. Function-2: changeDivSize()
3. Function-3: showDiv()

EDIT: If by default I hide the div, then resize + unhide it with javascript i still need to unhide it for people who don't have scripts enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. User clicks on a page link:
2. If scripts are enabled, hide the div.

This can be done in onload event as soon as the div is available.

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.display = "none";
```

Instead better option is using css:

```
#divId {
   display : none;
}
```

4) Resize DIV()

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.width = "440px";
```

5) Showing the div again

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.display = "block";
```

So your final code:

in css hide the div.

```
window.onload =  function() {
      var divEle = document.getElementById("divId");
      divEle.style.width = "440px";
      divEle.style.display = "block";
}
```

If javascript is disabled:

```
<noscript> 
  <style>
    #divId { 
        display: block;
     }
  </style>
 </noscript>
```

Comment: If i use onLoad="hideDiv" it still flashes on screen for a second - the problem is, if by default i hide it, i need to unhide it without javascript if scripts are not enabled

Comment: <noscript> <style>#divId { display: block;}</style></noscript>

Comment: i have updated answer. To avoid flashing hide it using css as i mentioned by default.

Comment: if you use hideDiv() method, the script need to wait till page loads. It may take time to load, so you are seeing the flashing. For that only i said about the css code. If your approach is same, then you can show it using noscript. But in case you want to use hideDiv() then we can't avoid flashing. One thing we can do to avoid flashing, but its not recommended. Just below the that particular div, add the script tag which calls hideDiv(), this can avoid flashing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got it working without the flashing - hidden by default, noscript tag to show it if disabled and javascript to resize then show it if it's enabled

Comment: Great! glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to hide the element before it is rendered by adding a class to the body element. First add a CSS rule that hides the div if the body has a specific class:

```
<style>
body.HideDiv #MyDiv { display: none; }
</style>
```

Then right after the body element exists add the class to it:

```
<body>
  <script>document.body.className='HideDiv';</script>
```

Once the div exists you can resize it and show it:

```
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
div.style.width = '200px';
div.style.height = '200px';
div.style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

If Javascript isn't enabled, the body never gets the class that hides the div, so the div will just remain visible.

Comment: "right after the body element exists add the class to it"  Doesn't CSS do that automatically? Why not apply the class _before_ it renders, hardcoded in your HTML?